# How to update state of parent component with a lifted up props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem with updating the state of parent component with a props from child component. It seems the following code is not working, however it looks fine

```
setUsersList(prevState => {
            return [...prevState, data];
        });
```

My parent component receives an object. Console.log(data) outputs the object received from child component. However, when console logging updated state (console.log(usersList)) it returns an empty array

Parent component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import AddUser from "./components/Users/AddUser";
import UsersList from "./components/Users/UsersList";

function App() {
    const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState([]);

    const addUserHandler = data => {
        console.log(data);
        setUsersList(prevState => {
            return [...prevState, data];
        });
        console.log(usersList);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <AddUser onAddUser={addUserHandler}></AddUser>
            <UsersList users={usersList}></UsersList>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Child component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "../UI/Button";
import Card from "../UI/Card";
import styles from "./AddUser.module.css";

const AddUser = props => {
    const [inputData, setInputData] = useState({ name: "", age: "" });

    const addUserHandler = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (
            inputData.age.trim().length === 0 ||
            inputData.name.trim().length === 0
        ) {
            return;
        }

        if (+inputData.age < 1) {
            return;
        }

        props.onAddUser(inputData);
        console.log(inputData.name, inputData.age);

        setInputData({ name: "", age: "" });
    };

    const usernameChangeHandler = event => {
        setInputData({ ...inputData, name: event.target.value });
    };

    const ageChangeHandler = event => {
        setInputData({ ...inputData, age: event.target.value });
    };

    return (
        <Card className={styles.input}>
            <form onSubmit={addUserHandler}>
                <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                <input
                    id="username"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={usernameChangeHandler}
                    value={inputData.name}
                ></input>
                <label htmlFor="age">Age (Years)</label>
                <input
                    id="age"
                    type="number"
                    onChange={ageChangeHandler}
                    value={inputData.age}
                ></input>
                <Button type="submit">Add User</Button>
            </form>
        </Card>
    );
};

export default AddUser;
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way react re-renders components, your console may not log with the expected state change. Instead you can use useEffect for debugging purposes:

`parent component`

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("usersList", usersList);
}, [usersList])
```

alternatively, having a console.log statement in the body of your functional component should log the correct 'usersList'.

```
const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState([]);
console.log("usersList", usersList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since setUserList is async function, you can not see the changes on console in the *addUserHandler* function.

```
function App() {
    const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState([]);

    const addUserHandler = data => {
        console.log(data);
        setUsersList(prevState => {
            return [...prevState, data];
        });
    };
    console.log(usersList);

    return (
        <div>
            <AddUser onAddUser={addUserHandler}></AddUser>
            <UsersList users={usersList}></UsersList>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

This will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The state variable won't change right away when you call `setState` function from the `useState` hook. Since it is an asynchronous event.

So you might need to write your code like this to see the right `console.log`

```
const addUserHandler = data => {
  console.log(data);
  setUsersList(prevState => {
    const temp = [...prevState, data];
    console.log(temp); // like this
    return temp;
  });
};
```

If the state is not updating in the UI. Please paste the error or the warning message.